# Как работает auto-property?

Tags: c#

Имеется такой код :

```
public List < Vector2 > PointList {
    get {
        return _points;
    }
    set {
        _points = value;
    }
}
```

Resharper предлагает заменить на auto-property

```
public List<Vector2> PointList { get; set; }
```

Подскажите как вообще работает auto-property?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^^"

Answer (score 2):

Auto-property сокращают код.

`public List<Vector2> PointList { get; set; }` - это тоже самое, что и в вашем случае:

```
List <Vector2> _points;
public List < Vector2 > PointList {
    get {
        return _points;
    }
    set {
        _points = value;
    }
}
```

Вот решарпер и предлагает упростить код. Убирается лишняя переменная `_points`, читается проще. На одном свойстве это может и не заметно, но если в классе куча таких полей, то у вас, по сути, было бы куча лишних переменных и куча похожих названий.

Если посмотреть, во что компилятор сгенерирует auto-property, то тоже самое будет. К примеру из:

```
public int IntProperty { get; private set; }
```

При генерации получится что-то вроде:

```
private int \u003CIntProperty\u003Ek__BackingField;

public int IntProperty
{
  get
  {
    return this.\u003CIntProperty\u003Ek__BackingField;
  }
  private set
  {
    this.\u003CIntProperty\u003Ek__BackingField = value;
  }
}
```